# How to destroy session when clicks on browser's back button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am flashing a success message using session->flash() method in laravel.
But when user clicks back button the message comes up again. How to fix this.
My code for showing message is -

```
@if(Session::get('success') )
    <script>
        swal({
            text: "{{Session::get('success')}}",
            button: localMsg.ok,

        }).then((isConfirm) => {
        });
    </script>
    @elseif(Session::get('error'))
    <script>
        swal({
            text: "{{Session::get('error')}}",
            button: localMsg.ok,

        }).then((isConfirm) => {
        });

    </script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You should destroy session values for success and error message

```
@if(Session::get('success') )
    <script>
        swal({
            text: "{{Session::get('success')}}",
            button: localMsg.ok,

        }).then((isConfirm) => {
        });
     {{ Session::forget('success'); }} //Add this line to destroy value for 'success'
    </script>
    @elseif(Session::get('error'))
    <script>
        swal({
            text: "{{Session::get('error')}}",
            button: localMsg.ok,

        }).then((isConfirm) => {
        });
     {{ Session::forget('error'); }} //Add this line to destroy value for 'error'
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: its removing sessions. even not display session message

Answer (score 1):

By This way you can get back button event of the browser:

```
     if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

        window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
          alert('Back button was pressed.'); //here you know that the back button is pressed
        //write code to hide your success message when your clicks on browser back button

        });

      }
```